# Rails: How to Automatically Loop Create Items based on foriegn_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn more complicated things than what I have been doing. So I started a personal project and immediately stuck.

I have models parent (Person - has_many) child (Checklist belongs_to) working well.

I have a model test (has_many) and attach it to questions(belongs_to) with test_id all working well. Both standard setup.

When on a Person (/person/1/checklists/new) I would like to find all the questions with the same test_id loop through it and attach it to a checklist (belongs_to question) and questions (has_many checklists).

```
  def create
   person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
   @checklist = person.checklists.new(ckecklist_params)
   # Above Works Fine (no idea what to do to loop through below)
   @question = Person.where(questions.test_id => person.test_id )
   @question.each do |test_builder|
      test_builder.create(?????)
   end
  end
```

I can post additional details and code, just trying to go beyond basics. Even a link pointing me in right direction would be great.